# Display related posts with same category or same tag return blank

Tags: categories, wp-query, tags, tax-query

I'm trying to display 4 related posted in the same category or have the same tag with the current post on the single post page. The result is just blank.

```
    <?php
      $rCateogry = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
      $rTag = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
      $args = 
        array( 
          'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'category',
              'field'    => 'id',
              'terms'    => $rCateogry,
            ),
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'tag',
              'field'    => 'id',
              'terms'    => $rTag,
            ),
          ),
          'numberposts' => 4,
          'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
        );
      $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <ul>
      <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
          <div class="feat-img">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
              <?php the_post_thumbnail("custom-ss"); ?>
            <?php endif ?>
          </div>
          <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
          </a>
          <?php get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); ?> 
        </li>
      <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The built in tag taxonomy is `post_tag`, not just `tag`. also, it's odd that the codex example for tax query shows `field` as `id`, but I'm fairly sure it should be `term_id`. try those two changes and see what your results are. also note that you can `var_dump( $query )` after you run the query and see if the query parameters are correctly set, anything invalid should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, I've already fixed it earlier. You are right, changing to `post_tag` does the trick. I had `field` as `id`, and it did work, but I have follow your suggestion and change it to `term_id`, which also works.